# What is the correct way in SQL for computing date tenure (Years and Months)?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am not expert in MySQL query.
I want to produce the tenure (Year and Month) base on these dates.

**Table**

| USERID | Date Hired | Separation Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017-10-02 | 2023-02-28 |
| 2 | 2009-01-10 | 2015-01-04 |

**Expected Output**

| USERID | TENURE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 Years and 4 Months |
| 2 | 5 Years and 11 Months |

I already Created a Query using DATEDIFF and convert days result into years and months but I always get wrong result. Can someone help me how to query this. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't shown us the query that doesn't work, or its wrong results.  It's hard to help without that information.

Comment: It is already answered. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try the following approach using `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` along with a `CASE` expression to handle the rendering of the months:

```sql
SELECT
    USERID,
    CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_hired, date_separated), ' Years',
           CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, date_hired, date_separated) % 12 > 0
                THEN CONCAT(' and ',
                            TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, date_hired, date_separated) % 12,
                            ' months')
                ELSE '' END) AS TENURE
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY USERID;
```

### Demo